# Extract cookies data in header

Tags: php, regex, cookies, http-headers, preg-match-all

I have this random string. I only need particular text inside the string such as `mcnb8h1apihg9ffav1ubtgal77`, and `Sat, 09-May-2015 11:49:58 GMT`

```
$str = 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 11:49:58 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.23-1~dotdeb.1 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=mcnb8h1apihg9ffav1ubtgal77; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 11:49:58 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/support/; domain=myweb.com; secure Location: index.php Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 11:49:58 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.23-1~dotdeb.1 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: OSTSESSID=sugrlug6sj8m27lrkv5id9v473; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 11:49:58 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/support/; domain=myweb.com; secure Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
```

This string is totally random. I try to solve it with:

```
$pattern = "#OSTSESSID=(.*); expires=(.*)\n#";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

but does not worked. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Any reason why `$_COOKIE['OSTSESSID']` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably [read up on Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) and the various operators you can use.

And use https://regex101.com/ as a great place to troubleshoot.

You've not provided much information about your data, is *OSTSESSID* the same length every time, always lower-case alphanumeric?

If we assume so, then here's a hint/half your answer:

```
$pattern = "/OSTSESSID=([a-z0-9]{26});/";
```

Hopefully this will help you with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The big reason it's not working is that you are getting a greedy match on the .*'s

It's trying to match as many characters as possible.  Throwing a question mark in after the star makes it ungreedy:

OSTSESSID=(.*?); expires=(.*?;)
(I also terminated the expires bit with a semi-colon
and just matches the snippets :

OSTSESSID=mcnb8h1apihg9ffav1ubtgal77; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 11:49:58 GMT;
and
OSTSESSID=sugrlug6sj8m27lrkv5id9v473; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 11:49:58 GMT;